# I want to add my logo to the slides header lines using xaringan

Tags: css, r, xaringan

I am using `xaringan` and I want to use the logo in all slides (except) the first and the inverted ones. I want to place the logo on the header line (heading level 1) however, using the `css` options (i.e. `background-position`) I 'm only able to put it immediately below the header line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fuction [`use_logo()`](https://github.com/gadenbuie/xaringanExtra#-logo) from the `xaringanExtra` package, solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `layout: true` and subsequent slides with use the template from that slide onwards. You can use `background-size` to set the size of your logo and `background-position` to set the position of the logo. E.g. `background-position: 10% 10%` means the left hand corner of your logo will be positioned 10% from the left and 10% from the top.

```
layout: true
background-image: url("your_logo.jpg")
background-size: 200px
background-position: 10% 10%

---

# Slide 2 should have logo

---

# Slide 3 should have logo

---

class: inverse

# Slide 4
```

If you don't want the logo to appear on where class is inverse then you can set the following in your css:

```
.inverse {
  background-image: none!important;
}
```

Comment: Where should I add the:

`layout: true
background-image: url("your_logo.jpg")
background-size: 200px
background-position: 10% 10%`

In the `.css`? Or directly in the `markdown`?

Comment: directly in the Rmd file

Comment: Could you put your whole Rmd file so I can see what you did?